# WIX 3.5 Visual Studio Project create Multiple MSI's For .NET Versions of Installed Files

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

Right now I have a WIX 3.5 project that lives in my VS 2010 solution.  It works great and compiles down to 1 MSI.

What I want is to have the 1 project potentially compile down to 2 MSI's.  One of the MSI's references a .NET 3.5 DLL that it is installing into the GAC, and the other MSI references a .NET 4.0 assembly that it is also installing into the GAC.

That way I can give the .NET respective MSI's to those depending on what framework they are on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your preference, you can either:

In this Solution panel/Project tree, have two separate projects; a .Net 3.5 and 4.0 projects, with the projects sharing files but different includes/build options.

or

Under the Build tab, pick "Configuration Manager" and "New", using the option to copy the current build to a new configuration. This is similar to having a Release/Debug version.
Here's an overview of this option:
[MSDN overview of VS Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

The advantage of the first method is the solution pane shows clearly that there are two builds (but its sort of redundant). The second is a bit cleaner, but a bit more hidden (and I'm pretty sure, you can only set the active project to build one configuration at a time).